# Soft Question: Scientific applications of ordinal arithmetic?

Tags: soft-question, ordinals

Are there any known scientific applications of ordinal arithmetic -- either direct applications or application of results in other areas that depend even indirectly on results from the study of ordinal arithmetic?

Comment: What's "scientific application"?

Comment: For example, ordinals helped von Neumann finish his Ph.D. and develop so many things including computers, nuclear weapons, quantum mechanics, and many other things. Do these things count as applications of ordinals?

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Are you saying he applied ordinals to quantum mechanics, etc?

Comment: No. I'm saying that he applied ordinals to getting a job.

Comment: Does this count? [**Graphs and Networks: Transfinite and Nonstandard**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0817642927) by Armen H. Zemanian. From the book description: *These new results, covering the mathematical theory of electrical circuits ...* I happened to see this book (advertised somewhere) shortly after it appeared in 2004, but I've never encountered a copy in a library or in a bookstore that I could look at.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Maybe. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: More than a century later, is there nothing else?

Comment: We're generally waiting for science to transcend finiteness. When they start talking about infinite computability, then they'll come to us [read: set theorists].

Comment: There are applications in computer science. Sometimes one need to use ordinals to prove termination of some algorithms.

Comment: Ordinals, as I see it, give us more expressive power and the possibility of measuring transfinite things, so it's hard to find direct real life applications.
 There are some (infinite) games played on automata where you use ordinals to compute the winning starting positions for each player. ("Playing Pushdown Parity Games in a Hurry" has some examples.)

Comment: $(\omega^{\omega^\omega}, +, \cdot)$, where $+$ and $\cdot$ are extensions of the nim sum and product, is isomorphic to the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$ where you can do some computations effectively. I don't know if that counts.